# FreeRtos porting with nabto windows 32

Tags: c, freertos

I am trying to port the nabto demo present in the below link
[github](https://github.com/nabto/appmyproduct-device-stub)

What I have done is the I have built the project based on the instruction provided on the link and after that included `freertos` source into it and tried to built the `heatpump` demo using the `freertos` when I compile it using visual studio I am getting the following errors

> unabto_main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _xTaskCreate referenced in function _nabto_demo
>
> unabto_main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _vTaskStartScheduler referenced in function _nabto_demo
>
> unabto_main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol_xQueueGenericCreate referenced in function _nabto_demo
>
> C:\Users\Sakthivel\Desktop\TEST2\appmyproduct-device-stub\build\Debug\amp_device_stub.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 3 unresolved externals
>
> Done building project "amp_device_stub.vcxproj" -- FAILED.

But all the related files headers are included in the project main file but it still shows the linking error.

Regards

Comment: Please read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix)

Answer (score 0):

This is not complaining about missing header files, but about missing source files.  Are you building FreeRTOS too?  xTaskCreate() is in the FreeRTOS tasks.c file, as is vTaskStartScheduler.  xQueueGenericCreate() is in the FreeRTOS queue.c source file.  Information on adding FreeRTOS to a project can be found on the following link: http://www.freertos.org/Creating-a-new-FreeRTOS-project.html